# Given that JavaScript has closures, what exactly is the purpose of the this keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following code, we can see that closures help contain the value of variables inside their scope:

```
var f = new Foo('jim','jam');
var b = new Bar('saul','paul');
var bz = new Baz();

function Foo(jim,jam){

    this.jim = jim;
    this.jam = jam;

    function log(){
        console.log('jim:',jim,'jam:',jam);
    }

    return log;
}


function Bar(jim,jam){

    function log(){
        console.log('jim:',jim,'jam:',jam);
    }

    return log;
}

function Baz(jim,jam){

    this.jim = 'bark';
    this.jam = 'catch';


    function log(){
        console.log('jim:',this.jim,'jam:',this.jam);
    }

    return log;
}

f();
b();
bz();
```

so, what exactly is the purpose of the '`this`' keyword in JavaScript then? When does it become necessary?

Comment: the `this` keyword allows you to pass a variable into the scope of the function without it being an argument in the function. so if i'm trying to reference window in a factory and window is unavailabled, i can call my function like `myClass['myfunction'].call(window, args);` effectively passing window as this.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what exactly it is that's confusing you. There's really not much in common between local variable scoping and closures, and object context.

Comment: @Pointy the overlap is it seems by returning an inner function from an outer function, you can reference those variables as if they were instance variables

Comment: @AlexMills your code is referencing the *parameters*, not the object properties. JavaScript *never* has implicit object references (except in `with` statement blocks, which are deprecated and weird).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword is used to access the current context, which is not the same as the current scope.

If you call a method of an object, the context for that call is the object. You can use the `this` keyword to access properties in the object:

```js
function Foo(jim,jam){
    this.x = jim;
    this.y = jam;
}

Foo.prototype.log = function(){
    document.write('jim:' + this.x + ', jam:' + this.y);
};

var f = new Foo('jim','jam');
f.log();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword is necessary when the context object must be referenced explicitly. Your functions are not really good examples, because you've used the same names for the object properties as you did for the function parameters. If you made them different, it might be more clear:

```
function Foo(pjim, pjam){

    this.jim = pjim;
    this.jam = pjam;

    function log(){
        console.log('jim:',jim,'jam:',jam);
    }

    return log;
}
```

That version will basically not work - the names "jim" and "jam" won't correspond to anything in the `log` function.